# Wait untill task is done with Selenium WebDriver for python

Tags: python, selenium, wait

I try to generate the 1000 best teams of a night on: https://www.fantasycruncher.com/lineup-rewind/draftkings/NHL/2019-02-03

However, it is only possible to generate 500 teams per iteration. Therefore, I need to click on the button `Calculate 500 more teams`, but that button is changing to stop once the browser is generating the first 500 teams. Therefore, I need to wait that the browser finish to generate the teams, and the button switch back to `Calculate 500 more teams` from the pending `Stop` button shown.

I tried to wait until the `Calculate`button is present with :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "calc-more-teams")))
```

Or is clickable :

```
calulatemorebutton=WebDriverWait(driver, 10000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "calc-more-teams")))
```

But, I always get a WebDriverException message that the button is not clickable at point ... Looking at the elements panel (by clicking inspect), I feel like the `Calculate 500 more teams`button is always there, but there is an alert , `Stop`, displayed when the browser is generating teams, and therefore I should proceed differently. I am trying to wait until that alert is not displayed, but did not succeed.

Here is the code working, but only with few teams generated. The code is working because I add some `time.sleep()`. However, if you increase the number of teams generated, the `webDriverwait` will be necessary and the code won't work...

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from datetime import date, timedelta
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


chromedriver =("C:/Users/Michel/Desktop/python/package/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

driver.get("https://www.fantasycruncher.com/lineup-rewind/draftkings/NHL/2019-02-03")

time.sleep(10)
closeButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name('close-login-alert')
closeButton.click()


# Generate lineups

Calculate_button = driver.find_element_by_id('calc-team')
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('select-objective'))
select.select_by_value("Actual_Pts")
lineups_textbox = driver.find_element_by_id('numOfLineups')
lineups_textbox.send_keys("10")
Calculate_button.click()

time.sleep(10)

closeButton2 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('swal2-confirm')
closeButton2.click()


# Calculate 500 more    
more = driver.find_element_by_class_name("run-results")
idid=more.get_attribute("id")
realid=idid+"-slider-input"
moremore=driver.find_element_by_id(realid)
moremore.clear()
moremore.send_keys("5")
time.sleep(10)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "calc-more-teams")))
calulatemorebutton=driver.find_element_by_class_name("calc-more-teams")
calulatemorebutton.click()

# # download csv    
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH , '//div[@data-action="downloadPlayerlist"]')))

download_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name(' export-csv-dropdown')
download_button.click()
csv= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-optid='export']")
csv.click()

time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

I expect to have 1000 teams generated and download the CSV file corresponding, but I am not able to generate the "500" more by waiting for the browser to generate the first group of 500 teams, and therefore for the `Stop` button to switch to `Calulate more`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly said, both the buttons('Stop' and 'Calculate # more teams') are always part of DOM, but normally "Stop" button is hidden by keeping its 'style' attribute to `display:none`. We can use this to identify your condition.

Once you have clicked on 'Calculate 500 more teams' button you can call this to wait for 'Stop' button to disappear.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".button.expand.stop-calc.alert")))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Did not load in time")
else:
    #download_your_csv
```

Comment: I try it and I obtain an error: "NameError: name 'TimeoutException' is not defined". How I define TimeoutException ?

Comment: You need to import it using `from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException`

Comment: How could I change the CSV name files ? I am looping through different dates and I would like to give the date as file name... Currently, the file name is automatically the current date and if I download more than one, the file name is the same but with numbers at the end such as (1), (2), (3), etc

Comment: This should get you started https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_rename.htm. Once you get a handle on that just name each file to include the date at the end instead of (1), (2), (3)